# how to set "TZ" environment variable at system level

Tags: windows, msdn

Can someone please tell me how to set the "TZ" environment variable at system level? And what should be its value for "China Standard Time"?

executing the below command in cmd prompt does not set the value at system level.
set TZ=CST8

Answer (score 1):

Run SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe then manage to set the variable.

or setx TZ CST8

You may need to restart cmd.exe

Comment: After setting the environemtal variable like this _tzname[0] return the time zone name as "CST". Shouldn't it return as "China Standard Time"?