# Time.new EINVAL error in string, Windows-only, rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby

This works on Unix, but when I move it over to Windows 7 (machine that script will be run on), using both Ruby 2.1 and 2.2, it fails.

This works (on Windows):

```
date = Time.new.localtime.to_s
file = File.new("somefile #{1 + 1}", 'a')
file.close
```

This does not work (on Windows):

```
date = Time.new.localtime.to_s
file = File.new("somefile #{date}", 'a')
file.close
```

The resulting error is:

```
test.rb:2:in 'initialize': Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - somefile 2015-12-07 11:17:52 -0500 (Errno::EINVAL)
          from test.rb:2:in 'new'
          from test.rb:2:in '<main>'
```

Any ideas on why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time is a red herring here. The problem is that the colon character (`:`) is not allowed in a filename on Windows. From MSDN:

> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including
>   Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set
>   (128–255), except for the following:
>
> - The following reserved characters:
>
>   - `<` (less than)
>   - `>` (greater than)
>   - `:` (colon)
>   - `"` (double quote)
>   - `/` (forward slash)
>   - `\` (backslash)
>   - `|` (vertical bar or pipe)
>   - `?` (question mark)
>   - `*` (asterisk)
> - Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII *NUL* character.
> - Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters
>     are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File
>     Streams.
> - Any other character that the target file system does not allow.
>
> *Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx*

One solution is to use [`Time#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) to output a string without the offending colons, e.g.:

```
date = Time.new.localtime.strftime("%F %H.%M.%S %z")
file = File.new("somefile #{date}", 'a')
# => #<File:somefile 2015-12-07 11.17.52 -0500>
```

Alternatively, take a look at this SO answer on the topic of sanitizing a string for use as a filename: [How to make a Ruby string safe for a filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939333/how-to-make-a-ruby-string-safe-for-a-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

`Time.new.localtime` looks for your systems's `ENV['TZ']` variable, which may not be set in Windows 7.

You can follow this link to set `ENV['TZ']` on Windows: [how to set "TZ" environment variable at system level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650018/how-to-set-tz-environment-variable-at-system-level)

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-localtime